# What resources are there on tone system creation?

Tags: list-of-languages, resource-request

What resources are there on tone system creation?
Resources could include

- Documentation on conlangs that have tone systems
- Guides on tone system creation
- Resources on tone in natural languages, for a posteriori naturalistic conlang creation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artifexian has a decent pair of videos ([#1](https://youtube.com/watch?v=XE4FrF5U0E0), [#2](https://youtube.com/watch?v=iaHYIXBvL94)) on tones which discusses various types of tone systems, how they work in natural languages, how they developed there, and ways you could work them in to a diachronic approach to conlanging. I don't think it discusses conlangs that do have tone systems though.

The Wikipedia page for [Four Tones (Middle Chinese)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_tones_(Middle_Chinese)) also does a decent job of discussing the evolution of tone across the Sinitic languages.